# My regular expression matches too much. How can I tell it to match the smallest possible pattern?

Tags: regex

I have this RegEx:

```
('.+')
```

It has to match character literals like in C. For example, if I have `'a' b 'a'` it should match the a's and the `'`'s around them.

However, it also matches the `b` also (it should not), probably because it is, strictly speaking, also between `'`'s.

Here is a screenshot of how it goes wrong (I use this for syntax highlighting):
[image: screenshot]

I'm fairly new to regular expressions. How can I tell the regex not to match this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is being greedy and matching the first apostrophe and the last one and everything in between.

This should match anything that isn't an apostrophe.

```
('[^']+')
```

Another alternative is to try non-greedy matches.

```
('.+?')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. What does "greedy" exactly mean in regular expressions?

Comment: Won't work with `'\''`, which is a char literal in C (as the question states, it needs to match them).`

Comment: This page, http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html, can explain better than I can explain. Basically, it will match as much as possible when it is greedy.

Comment: @sidyll perhaps `('([^'\\]|\\.)*')` then? It worked.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a non-greedy version, e.g. `('.+?')`?

There are usually two *modes* of matching (or two sets of quantifiers), maximal (greedy) and minimal (non-greedy). The first will result in the longest possible match, the latter in the shortest. You can read about it (although in perl context) in the [Perl Cookbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=IzdJIax6J5oC&pg=PT246&lpg=PT246&dq=%22Greedy%20and%20Non-Greedy%20Matches%22&source=bl&ots=z7xffxdciO&sig=n3Imp5-QjoQaazshZfc4WUZI1g8&hl=en&ei=Vr1CTv_SM8v_-ga-yYG2CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22Greedy%20and%20Non-Greedy%20Matches%22&f=false) (Section 6.15).

Comment: This is good advice for Perl-compatible regexes, but an error (which often simply fails quietly) for other regex dialects.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
('[^']+')
```

The ^ means include every character except the ones in the square brackets. This way, it won't match `'a' b 'a'` because there's a `'` in between, so instead it'll give both instances of `'a'`

Comment: The `^` in your example is being used as an anchor. It needs to be inside the brackets to work as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the qutoes:

```
\'[^\']+\'
```

Edit: Hmm, we'll I suppose this answer depends on what lang/system you're using.

Comment: It's ObjC: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html