# findall not retruning all the results in Python 3.7

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to create list of tuples with the data after strings `string1` and `string3`. But not getting expected result.

```
s = 'string1:1234string2string3:a1b2c3string1:2345string3:b5c6d7'
re.findall('string1:(\d+)[\s,\S]+string3:([\s\S]+',s)
```

Actual result:

```
[('1234', 'b5c6d7)']
```

Expected result:

```
[('1234', 'a1b2c3'), ('2345', 'b5c6d7')]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My regular expression matches too much. How can I tell it to match the smallest possible pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014903/my-regular-expression-matches-too-much-how-can-i-tell-it-to-match-the-smallest)

Comment: a little far fetched duplicate. Related, yes, exact duplicate, well no since it requires some more work to make that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You current regex uses `[\s,\S]+` which is greedy and matches all characters until the end of the line.

You could make it non greedy and use a positive lookahead `(?=string|$)` for the last match that assert what follows is either `string` or the end of the line `$`.

[`string1:(\d+).*?string3:(.*?)(?=string|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/2Qnhsw/1)

```
import re 
s = 'string1:1234string2string3:a1b2c3string1:2345string3:b5c6d7'
print(re.findall('string1:(\d+).*?string3:(.*?)(?=string|$)',s))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PNOOI52036)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `[\s,\S]+` is greedy and therefore consuming everything between the first string1 and the last string3.

You can fix that by using positive lookaheads and making the regex non greedy like this:

```
string1:(\d+)[^\d][\s,\S]+?string3:([\s\S]+?(?=string|$))
```