# Pattern Matching Reg Ex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am a beginner for the regular expressions pattern matching in python.
please help me to solve this problem.

I want to extract some texts from the given string. Please check the below example.

> String :
>   "keyword//match1/match2/more_text_with_/_more_and_more_/_texts"
>
> I need to extract "match1" and "match2"

I wrote the following python code to do that...

```
import re
astr = 'keyword//match1/match2/more_text_with_/_more_and_more_/_texts'
match = re.search('keyword//(.*)/(.*)/.*', astr)

print("match1 : ", match.group(1))
print("match2 : ", match.group(2))
```

The result is...

```
match1 :  match1/match2/more_text_with_                                                                     
match2 :  _more_and_more_
```

I read about "How Regex Engine Works" from here https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html

And I can understand why this result comes. But I have no idea to write a regular expression to get my required matching texts.

Please help me with this.

Thank you very much,

Comment: The `.*` matches too much. Try `keyword//([^/]+)/([^/]+)/`

Comment: You are an awsome guy brother. It's working. Thank you very much for your quick help. Please add this as an answer. I can give you an upvote. :)

Comment: ready about greedy pattern too

Comment: There are duplicates about this issue. This page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop  and this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014903/my-regular-expression-matches-too-much-how-can-i-tell-it-to-match-the-smallest explains it in detail.

Comment: is it always in this format? you might not need regex

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is greedy and will match as many characters as possible, instead you could use `.*?` which will match as few characters as possible.

```
import re

astr = 'keyword//match1/match2/more_text_with_/_more_and_more_/_texts'
match = re.search(r'keyword//(.*?)/(.*?)/.*?', astr)

print("match1 : ", match.group(1))
print("match2 : ", match.group(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way not using the *non-greedy* `.*?` (See answer posted by @NegativeChameleon):

`match = re.search(r'keyword//([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/', astr)`

`[^\/]*` says to match 0 or more characters that are not a `'/'` and you can be as greedy as you want!

```
import re

astr = 'keyword//match1/match2/more_text_with_/_more_and_more_/_texts'
match = re.search(r'keyword//([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/', astr)

print("match1:", match.group(1))
print("match2:", match.group(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy)

```
import re
astr = 'keyword//match1/match2/more_text_with_/_more_and_more_/_texts'
match = re.search('keyword//([^/]*)/([^/]*)/.*/', astr)

print("match1 : ", match.group(1))
print("match2 : ", match.group(2))
```

output:

```
('match1 : ', 'match1')
('match2 : ', 'match2')
```

base on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53368989/8767186)

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall('(.+?)/',s.replace('keyword//',''))[0:2]
```

would also work

examples:

```
s = 'keyword//match1/match2/more_text_with_/_more_and_more_/_texts'
```

output:

```
['match1', 'match2']

s = 'keyword//ma13*41$?tch1/mad4#$(#01tch2/more_text_with_/_more_and_more_/_texts'
```

output:

```
['ma13*41$?tch1', 'mad4#$(#01tch2']
```